# Case statement gives unexpected output

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a subquery producing some rows like this:

```
| year | quarter | id | status |
|------|---------|----|--------|
| 2020 | 4       | 1  | no     |
| 2021 | 1       | 1  | yes    |
|      |         |    |        |
```

I then want to add an extra column to track status change. I have tried this:

```
select
    *,
    case
        when (year = 2020 and quarter = 4 and status = 'no') and (year = 2021 and quarter = 1 and status = 'yes')
    then 1 else 0
    end as status_change_during_2021_q1
from(
    ...
    ...
) t
order by id, year, quarter
limit 50
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
| year | quarter | id | status | status_change_during_2021_q1 |
|------|---------|----|--------|------------------------------|
| 2020 | 4       | 1  | no     | 0                            |
| 2021 | 1       | 1  | yes    | 0                            |
```

I do not understand why the second row isn't set to 1 for status_change...?

Comment: You cannot have year equal both 2020 and 2021 at the same time. Maybe you wanted `or` condition there? Or you look for difference between rows? This needs window functions or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare values *across* rows.  Use `lag()`:

```
(case when status = 'yes' and
           lag(status) over (partition by id order by year, quarter) = 'no'
      then 1 else 0
 end)
```

Your version *cannot* do anything useful, because, for instance, `year` cannot be both `2021` and `2020` in the same row.

Comment: I was specifying the year and quarter explicitly in my case statement. It looks like this solution will always compare to the previous row. So I think this will be more 'status_changed_to_yes_since_previous_quarter' (?). Should still work though

Comment: @cs_guy . . . Yes, that is the logic that this implements -- but per `id`.